# jquery errors in Wordpress admin panel

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm having a lot of errors in the admin panel of my Wordpress site.

[image]

This is making impossible to use some visual form builder as WPForms or Gravity.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, hard to say but it can be a plugin conflict. I would start deactivating the plugins and themes **one by one**, and on each deactivation, you can check if JS errors are still there.

When the errors are gone, you have probably located the plugin which is conflicting, and then decides if you can just remove it, or debug it deeper, and fix the conflict.

Keep in mind that conflict is a specific combination, so you should try a lot. If you understand JS, you can open the error and locate the bug directly from the code.

Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Deactivating all the plugins one by one, I realised the error was in the plugin I created to use DataTables. It used a minified and concatenated js and css, so, modifying this code it seems to be solved. Thanks FrancescoCarlucci!

Comment: @Alex you are welcome ;) please mark the answer as correct if you want, it will be a good indication for others with the same issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned above in a comment to Francesco, the error was in my own plugin that used a concatenated css and js file.

The code was this one:

```
function utm_user_scripts() {
$plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
wp_enqueue_style( 'admin-dt-css', $plugin_url . "DataTables/datatables.min.css");
wp_enqueue_script( 'admin-dt-js',  $plugin_url . "DataTables/datatables.min.js");
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'utm_user_scripts' );
```

I changed it and now the code imports each js and css one by one, not concatenated (to avoid jquery incompatibility.

```
function import_scripts(){ ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.2/css/colReorder.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/searchpanes/1.0.1/css/searchPanes.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/css/select.dataTables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.2/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/searchpanes/1.0.1/js/dataTables.searchPanes.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<?php }
```